# How to internet explorer properties window in C#

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, settings

I am working on a windows application, where i have to provide the user, a way to change the proxy settings by opening the IE settings window. Google chrome uses the same method, when you try to change the proxy settings in chrome, it will open internet explorer properties window with the connection tab selected.

I have observed that chrome is running run32dll.exe to achieve this, but it is also passing some arguments along with it

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "SomeArgumentsHere");`

my only problem is i don't know what arguments it is passing.

To simplify my question, i want to know a way to open IE settings window with the connection tab selected, from my C#.net application

**Update** the following code worked for me

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("inetcpl.cpl", ",4");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the complete command passed by Google chrome (obtained using Process Explorer):

```
"C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL C:\Windows\system32\inetcpl.cpl,,4
```