# How to integrate windows/Internet explorer's internet properties options and proxy?

Tags: c++, windows, http-proxy

I wonder if what APIs does Chrome uses when working with proxies. I noticed that when you try and set the proxy (thru Settings->Advanced->Open Proxy Settings) It pop's up a window (Internet Properties) in which I noticed running from `rundll32.exe`. So I wonder, how do I simulate this in my own application? (C++)

I wanna put a button on my GUI application, and when it's clicked, pop's-up the Internet Proerties Window where the user can see the proxies options and set it too if they want, just like chrome's and internet explorer's. Do I simply launch `rundll32.exe` with the same arguments as chrome passed to it? or is there any other APIs that automatically does this?

And how do I get those proxy settings entered by the user? Thanks.

Comment: Here is the documentation from msdn [launching-the-internet-properties-dialog-from-c#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/robgruen/2005/02/02/launching-the-internet-properties-dialog-from-c/) or duplicated question [how-to-internet-explorer-properties-window-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311526/how-to-internet-explorer-properties-window-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to internet explorer properties window in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4311526/how-to-internet-explorer-properties-window-in-c-sharp)